# PHP / .htaccess - Redirect to specific folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am creating a PHP project, and the folder structure looks something like:

```
includes/ 
pages/
config/
```

In theory, all of the pages will go into the `pages` folder. But, whenever someone visits the website, on a specific page: (i.e.) `www.mysite.com/help` I want it to look inside the `pages/` folder, rather than thinking it is on the root of the document.

Can I achieve this using PHP / .htaccess - I have googled this problem and cannot see any relevant  infomation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule in /root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

#if "/document_root/pages/foo" is an existent file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1 -f
#rewrite /foo to /pages/foo
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache supports URL rewriting as explained here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?help/?(.*) /pages/$1  [L]
```